# mutability with nested objects with es6 and redux

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

Wrong mutation of nested object, the uom_id gets [ null, null ] and it should always have a value.

```
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        console.log('ADD TO CART', {...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.product)))})
        const ex = state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`] ? {
            ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`]))),
            quantity: state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`].quantity + 1,
            uom_id: [ payload.product.uom_id[0], payload.product.uom_id[1]],
            section: payload.section
        } : {
                ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.product))),
                section: payload.section,
                uom_id: [ payload.product.uom_id[0], payload.product.uom_id[1]] ,
                quantity: 1
            };
            console.log('THIS IS THE EX, ', ex);
        return {
            ...state,
            shoppingCart: {
                ...state.shoppingCart,
                [`c_${payload.product.default_code}`]: state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`] ? {
                    ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`]))),
                    quantity: state.shoppingCart[`c_${payload.product.default_code}`].quantity + 1,
                    uom_id: [ payload.product.uom_id[0], payload.product.uom_id[1]],
                    section: payload.section
                } : {
                        ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.product))),
                        section: payload.section,
                        uom_id: [ payload.product.uom_id[0], payload.product.uom_id[1]],
                        quantity: 1
                    },
            }
        }
```

I expect the object be copied with nested levels.

[ct in the image you can see the first object as the payload and after the result of ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wU08.png)

Comment: In the image focus on uom_id that becomes null.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read this in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your payload object has a product object within a product object.

As such:

```
{ 
   payload : { 
              product : {
                          product : {

                          },
                          section: undefined
              }
   }
}
```

Therefore you would have to use `payload.product.product.uom_id[0]` to get your values.

Also, I recommend using deconstructing assignments for objects and arrays to help clean up the code structure. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Eg.

```
const { product: { product } } = payload
```

where this `product` variable would be the same as `payload.product.product`

Comment: Hi CodeYute, thank you for reading this. I have done the following but still one of the items in the shopping cart gets uom_id: [ null, null ] and i font know really why.  Here is the image of the new reducer

Comment: did you change the other code lines to use `payload.product.product`?

Comment: `{
                    ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.product))),
                    section: payload.section,
                    uom_id: [...payload.product.uom_id],
                    quantity: 1
                };
                console.log('THIS IS THE EX, ', ex);`
Srry I could not post that correctly, so far thats what I have changed, let me destructurize it further

Comment: console.log the `payload` I think you will see the nested variables better.

Comment: I have this so far ` console.log('ADD TO CART', {...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)))})
            const ex = state.shoppingCart[`c_${product.default_code}`] ? {
                ...(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.shoppingCart[`c_${product.default_code}`]))),
                quantity: state.shoppingCart[`c_${product.default_code}`].quantity + 1,
                uom_id: [...product.uom_id],
                section
            }`

Comment: Use `const { product: { product, section } } = payload`
because you have a nested product inside your product